# How to Create a Join Column with a static value in TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to establish a polymorphic relation in TypeORM where I need to set up a customized join column. Specifically, I want to use two columns: `record_id` and `record_type`. The value in the `record_type` column should be a constant and match the name of the parent entity.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'attachments' })
export class Attachment {
  ...

  @ManyToOne(() => Advertisement, (advertisement) => advertisement.attachments)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'record_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    { name: 'record_type', value: 'Advertisement' },
  ])
  advertisement: Advertisement

  @ManyToOne(() => Blog, (blog) => blog.attachments)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'record_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    { name: 'record_type', value: 'Blog' },
  ])
  blog: Blog
}
```

The challenge here is that TypeORM doesn't directly support static values for `@JoinColumn`. Therefore, the syntax `{ name: 'record_type', value: 'Blog' }` is incorrect. Are there any workarounds available to address this limitation? Your insights are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround by using `@BeforeInsert` and `@BeforeUpdate` decorators.

You can modify your entity as this:

```
@Entity({ name: 'attachments' })
export class Attachment {
  ...

  @Column()
  record_id: number;

  @Column()
  record_type: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Advertisement, (advertisement) => advertisement.attachments)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'record_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  advertisement: Advertisement;

  @ManyToOne(() => Blog, (blog) => blog.attachments)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'record_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  blog: Blog;

  // Additional logic to determine the correct parent entity and set record_type accordingly
}
```

And you can add the logic for Entity listeners like this:

```
@BeforeInsert()
@BeforeUpdate()
setRecordType(): void {
  if (this.advertisement) {
    this.record_type = 'Advertisement';
  } else if (this.blog) {
    this.record_type = 'Blog';
  }
}
```